# Did Leia and Jyn know each other?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, princess-leia

In the second issue of the *Rogue One* comic book adaptation, there is a flashback scene of Saw Gerrera and Bail Organa arguing over a holotable. The whatever event must have taken place before Gerrera abandoned Jyn, around 5 BBY.

[image]

In the image, young Jyn Erso was standing next to Gerrera, and little princess Leia stood on the opposite side. As the girls were almost the same age (only two years apart), both surrounded only by grown-up rebels, they might have had some interest to interact with each other. Do we know if the two young ladies were actually acquainted?

Comment: comics are canon so this detail is too - that's a good question

Comment: Who knows, who cares ? :D When introducing these supporting characters into main story, it is common to give them some history with leading characters, as a means to endear them to not-so-bright public. This is so called "small world" literary technique. So it could be expected  that Jyn Erso and Galen Erso will meet significant figures in SW universe in future comics, books and maybe even movies .

Comment: fwiw - so far Leia has crossed paths with Sabine in both Star Wars Rebels as well as in the canon micro-series Forces of Destiny. Sabine and Jyn will be in an episode together in late October, but so far Leia and Jyn have not met that we know of

Comment: This piece of canon obviously contradicts the latest novel 'Leia, Princess of Alderaan'. Get your act together, Disney!

Answer (score 2):

#### It is unlikely

They may have known *of* each other, but it is not likely they knew each other.

Leia was the "daughter" of a senator, and was raised in a semi-royal environment on Alderaan. Jyn was the ward of a resistance fighter, and was raised either on the run or in the underbelly of the galactic community.

Neither girl was around the other for any length of time, even the two men (Saw and Bail) probably rarely saw each other. And when they did, they probably didn't have the girls with them every time.

If they did happen to be in the same environment, the class difference would have made it unlikely they would have interacted.

So in short, there is no canon (or sociological) reason for them to have been acquainted.

Comment: Two bored young girls, approximately the same age, hanging around with nothing to do, ***while their parents talk about boring stuff for hours on end?*** I'd say that they have every possible sociological reasons to chat among themselves.

Comment: If the comic showed them standing near each other during the long, boring conversations, I might agree with you. But it doesn't. Thus my answer. Awareness or even slight interaction does not mean they knew each other.

Comment: The comic shows them within a few yards of each other.

Comment: On opposites sides of the table next to their respective guardians. They look like uncomfortable children in a foreign environment near the only thing that they know.

Comment: keep an eye on the Forces of Destiny canon shorts - if there is a connection, it will turn up there most likely